# How do I read a zipped TSV file to dataframe on Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am attempting to use Databricks to read data from a compressed TSV file on an SFTP however am having difficulties (was attempting to use pysftp and SQLContext to read the TSV). Does anybody have some sample code or a link to resources/videos that will explain how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the end:

```
with ftp.open("TestFile.zip") as f:
    dfTest = pd.read_csv(f, compression='zip', sep='\t')
```